# How to place html dynamically right after the body tag but within the body tag? jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, plugins

I need to add some html right after the body tag so like :

```
<body>
<p>this is the HTML I need to add</p>
</body>
```

Here is my jQuery code :

```
jQuery(document).ready(addPageFlipHTML);

function addPageFlipHTML() {

    jQuery('body') // after body tag
            .after(
                    "<div id='pageflip'><a href='http://sabwd.com'><img src='/test/wp-content/plugins/page-flip/images/page_flip.png' alt='' />" //create this html
                            + "<span class='msg_block'>Subscribe via RSS</span></a></div>");

}
```

Does anyone know how to do this? I am trying to write a universal plugin and need a definite tag like body to add after but inside.

Thanks in Advance,

Mike

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To position new content inside the opening `<body>` element, you want the [`prepend()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) method  instead:

```
jQuery('body') 
        .prepend(
                "<div id='pageflip'><a href='http://sabwd.com'><img src='/test/wp-content/plugins/page-flip/images/page_flip.png' alt='' />" //create this html
                        + "<span class='msg_block'>Subscribe via RSS</span></a></div>");
```

The reason is that `jQuery('body')` doesn't select the opening `<body>` tag, but rather the entire `<body></body>` element.

So the [`after()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/after/) method was attempting to place the new content after `</body>`, which is invalid. But `.prepend()` places new content *inside* the `body` *(and before any other content that may be inside)*.

Comment: Thanks Patrick that did the trick ! I will click it right after 9 min it says.